# Where can I find the exact base pairs for a specific gene, e.g. SRY (sex determining region Y)?

Tags: gene

Per a [quora answer](https://qr.ae/pvJgiZ), the Sex-determining Region Y (SRY) gene contains 14 bp. I searched the gene on [NIH](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/6736) and [genenames](https://www.genenames.org/data/gene-symbol-report/#!/hgnc_id/HGNC:11311) and get just the info about the gene itself.

Where can I find those exact 14 base pairs for the gene?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the information on Quora is wrong: The SRY gene transcript is 828 nucleotides long and encodes for a protein of 204 amino acids. 14 base pairs would only code for 4 amino acids which is not really a functional protein.

You can download sequence information from Ensembl (or also the NCBI if you like, the datasets behind it are the same). Go to the [Ensembl Website](https://www.ensembl.org/index.html) choose human and type in the gene you are looking for.

You will get back a page which looks like the following:

[image]

On the left side you can now either click on "exons" or "cDNA" to get a closer look on the sequence:

[image]

This is what you get when you choose cDNA. It shows the complete transcript in the first line, the processed, protein coding sequence in the middle and the protein sequence below each triplett. You also have a download button for the sequences, if you press it, you can decide which information you want to have (full transcript, mRNA...) and the format (simple text or annotated rtf file):

[image]

Choose the information you are looking for and then save it to your computer.